# Check if JQueryUI button exists before destroying?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Lets say I have the following code:

**JS:**

```
$('.remove').button("destroy");
```

If I were to run this before .button() is called, I get an error in the console like the following:

`Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'`

How can I check to see if a button was actually created before attempting to destroy it?

Comment: jquery ui version used

Comment: I'm impressed how many different ways there were to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.remove.ui-button').button("destroy");
```

Comment: Your solution is the least amount of lines, pretty nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$('.remove').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data().uiButton != undefined
}).button('destroy')
```

Comment: that is an interesting way to do it too.  Is that better than what I came up with?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this -

```
if ($('.remove').hasClass("ui-button"))
{
    // Button exists
}
else
{
    // Button does not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to take advantage of "create" button

create a global variable

```
var created=false;
```

while applying ui to button

```
$('button').button({create:function(){created=true;}});
```

while removing

```
if(created==true) 
{
  // destroy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out

```
if($('.remove').is(":ui-button")){
     $('.remove').button("destroy");
}
```